# Apply CSS to a unique li inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to change CSS properties for a specific `li` inside `ng-repeat`, the loop:

```
<li id="cmmnt{{$index}}" ng-repeat="comment in ad.comments | orderBy : sortComment : true">
          <div class="commentTextArea">
            <p id="commentText">{{comment.text | limitTo: 100 }}</p>
           <a ng-click="changeEm('cmmnt'+$index)" ng-show="comment.text.length>=10"> {{moreLessText}}
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"  style="color: #ee4a4a;"></i>
           </a>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

the `ng-click="changeEm('cmmnt'+$index)"` need to change the height(`style.maxHeight`) of the `li`by ID. 
here is the function:

```
$scope.changeEm = function(liElement){ document.getElementById("'liElement'").style.maxHeight ="1em;!important";}
```

In the `console.log()` for `'liElement'` is just a string and I cant find it by `document.getElementById("'liElement'")`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a string as variable instead of the variable you pass into the function. I wouldn't recommend this approach, but you can fix it by changing this:

```
document.getElementById("'liElement'")
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById(liElement)
```

The approach I would recommend is to use ng-class instead:

```
<li id="cmmnt{{$index}}" 
    ng-class="{ 'active': comment.clicked }"
    ng-repeat="comment in ad.comments | orderBy : sortComment : true">
    <div class="commentTextArea">
        <p class="commentText">{{comment.text | limitTo: 100 }}</p>
        <a ng-click="changeEm(comment)" ng-show="comment.text.length>=10"> {{moreLessText}}
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="color: #ee4a4a;"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

and in your changeEm function:

```
$scope.changeEm = function(comment) {
    comment.clicked = true;
}
```

Then you can use the 'active' class in your css:

```
/* the 'p' in non-clicked 'li' */
li p.commentText {
    max-height: 10px;
}
/* the 'p' in a clicked 'li' */
li.active p.commentText {
    max-height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes it return all the object, how do I apply the css for the commentText ?

Comment: `li p.commentText` for you basic text and `li.active p.commentText {}` for the clicked ones. You should add a class to the p instead of an id, because you generate multiple of the same id's which isn't valid html

Comment: your code does not work. it work on all comment instead of only the text.

Comment: You might be just misinterpret it. This code puts an 'active' class on the 'li' when you click the 'a'. Then you can just use this css class to target your elements within that class

Comment: Still I dont know how to target the <p> element, so I can apply CSS on it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple, I just add `ng-class`:

```
<div class="commentTextArea">
            <p id="commentText" ng-class="comment.active==true?'visable':'notVisable'">{{comment.text}}</p>
          </div>
```

and the function :

```
$scope.changeEm = function(comment){
                    console.log(comment);
                    comment.active = true;
                }
```

finally the match CSS:

```
.visable {
    height: 6.5em !important;
    overflow: visible!important;
}
.notVisable{
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

Hopes that helps someone!